# sci-fi animated series from 80s-90s identification

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

Can anyone help me identify an animated series I remember from the early 90s.
Below are few highlights I remember about it:

- action took place in space and/or planets (for sure there was some shooting with fancy fighter-ships in space)
- protagonists were a team of people serving in some kind of (military?) organization (some of them used nicknames at least in the dubbed version), but I don't remember anything more specific
- antagonists had a mother ship from which they launched their assaults (they also had triangle-shaped fighter-ships from which they launched smaller triangle-shaped ships)
- graphics similar to "Centurions," so nothing too cartoonish and nothing 3D (and I'm rather sure it wasn't anime)

I remember the series because at that time I was hyped about fighter planes and fighter pilots (regardless if it was in space or not).

It's not "G-force" or "Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors."

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where did you see it?  Do you know what the original language was?

Comment: No idea about original language (I was too young to remember) also it was on local TV chanel (so the series might be even from late 70s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triangle-shaped space ships make me think that this was [StarCom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starcom:_The_U.S._Space_Force): The U.S. Space Force.

I don't remember the show, but I had one or two of the toys. According to wikipedia, a few of the characters' nicknames were: Crowbar, Dakota, Cowboy, Slim, Dash, Bandit, and Bronx.

The show ran in the late 80s, but apparently reruns were broadcast in the early 90s.

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks!